# Best program to clone partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, disk-cloning

I need to directly clone two different partitions; I will be storing the two clones on another hard drive.

Are there any good quality programs that anyone can recommend? I'm looking for stability in the program.

Comment: This will get closed as a duplicate, but in my opinion, THE best for cloning a partition, or entire drive is Acronis: http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/ It is only $30 right now, although you can buy an add-on to do bare-metal restores and some other features: http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/#plus-pack A lot of people like free Clonezilla, which is also very good.

Comment: Please don't double-post your questions. If you need to clarify your question, just use the [edit] button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really love Clonezilla.
Free.
Stable.
Linux-based.
Saves on network shares.
No problems with usb or sata.
Clones Windows, Linux and Mac Os partitions (and more) or disks.
With a graphical interface so easy that's boring...

Can we ask for more?

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll take a look at the program and get back to you.

Comment: You'll be happy :)

Comment: We could ask for online cloning :P