# Software to clone HFS+ partition

Tags: clone, disk-cloning, hfs+, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best program to clone partition](https://superuser.com/questions/312868/best-program-to-clone-partition)

I need to clone/backup an entire partition from a Mac Drive, is there any software that can clone the partition for restoring later on?

Thanks